# binding configuration to Names in guice recursively

Tags: configuration, jackson, guice, dropwizard

My application has configurations which are loaded using parsing annotations into a file using Jackson's fasterxml annotations. For example:

```
public class RootConfiguration extends Configuration {

  @JsonProperty
  @NotEmpty
  public String foo;

  @JsonProperty
  public BarConfiguration bar;

  public class BarConfiguration extends Configuration {
    @JsonProperty
    public String baz;      
  }
}
```

The configuration is then injected into providers in my `Module` that help me bind those properties to places in the code that use them. Like so:

```
  @Provides
  @Named("config")
  public RootConfiguration provideRootConfiguration(RootConfiguration configuration) {
    return configuration;
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("config.foo")
  public String provideFooConfiguration(RootConfiguration configuration) {
    return configuration.foo;
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("config.bar")
  public BarConfiguration provideBarConfiguration(RootConfiguration configuration) {
    return configuration.bar;
  }
```

And so on.

I'm looking for a framework to help me avoid this tedious work.

I would imagine something that looks like this:

```
@Configuration(value = "config", bindSubProperties = true)
public class RootConfiguration extends Configuration {
...
```

That would use Reflection to bind any sub fields in my class as guice `Names`.
I've looked into `Governator`'s annotations for configurations but as far as I can see they need to be applied to every configuration that I want to bind, which saves me some coding, but is essentially the same (I still have to manually specify the path for each and every configuration I want to bind).

Before I roll out my own implementation for this, is there something that will give me what I need?

Note: I'm using this for a `Dropwizard` project so the constraint on using Jackson to map the configuration to POJOs is rather tight (unless I move the application configuration outside of the config yaml).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tool that would do this for you, but you could do it yourself pretty easily with something like this:

```java
void bindConfiguration() {
    for (Field field : RootConfiguration.class.getFields() {
        bindConfiguration(TypeLiteral.get(field.getGenericType()), field);
    }
}

<T> void bindConfiguration(TypeLiteral<T> type, Field field) {
    bind(type)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named("config." + field.getName()))
            .toProvider(new ConfigurationProvider<T>(field))
            .in(Singleton.class);
}

class ConfigurationProvider<T> implements Provider<T> {
    private final Field field;
    @Inject RootConfiguration configuration;

    ConfigurationProvider(Field field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return (T) field.get(configuration);
    }
}
```